# Fancyhdr and Epigraph Problem with page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I used the fancyhdr package and put the page numbers on the left/right side at the bottom of the page. Then I used the epigraph package to put a quote on top of a chapter page. The problem is that when I insert the epigraph, the page numbering is in the middle of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} %chapter oben ohne Nummer 
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1} %macht das nich alles Großgeschrieben wird 

\fancyhead{} %löscht den Standardtext oben 
\fancyhead[LE] {\leftmark} %chaptername=current language bezeichnung für Kapitel, \chaptermark= Titel; Text in{} wird links bzw. rechts gestzt (gerade und ungerade Seiten)
\fancyhead[RO] {\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO] {\thepage} %the page returns page number; R=Right O=Odd page L=LEft E=even page
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt} %dicke vom Strich
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % empty pagestyle plan (für Seiten mit Chapter o.ä)
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    }

   

\usepackage{epigraph} % für vorangestellte Zitate
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt} %entfernt die Linie
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.5\linewidth} % breite vom epigraph
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright} %rechtsbündig
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushright} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Title of Chapter one}
\epigraphhead[50]{\epigraph{\textit{This a famous quote.}}{--- Famous Person}}
\section{Section Title}
\blindtext 
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\blindtext[15]
\end{document}
´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, more a guide to a solution. The `\epigraphhead` macro changes the page style in order to print the epigraph in the correct left/right location. The `epigraph` pagestyle is a version of the `plain` page style which is the typical pagestyle for chapters. I think that you will have to redefine this page style (see the code in the manual `texdoc epigraph`). I have never used `fancyhdr` and it's far too late (in years) for me to try.

I think that this might be the way for you to go.

Copy `epigraph.sty` to `epigraph2.sty` (in your working directory). Then edit `epigraph2.sty`.

In the line `\ProvidesPackage{epi...}[...] replace` epigraph`with`epigraph2` and suitable optional data.

Almost at the end of the file replace

```
\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}
\let\@evenfoot\oddfoot}
```

with

```
\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage}
\def\@evenfoot{\reset@font\thepage\hfil}}
```

And then in your document `\usepackage{epigraph2}`

The new definitions of `\@oddfoot` and `\@evenfoot` for the `epigraph pagestyle` match, I hope, your document's pagestyle.

I feel that it would be too difficult (i.e., I have no idea how to do it) to extend `epigraph` to cater for all the pagestyles that might be applied for chapter pages so I'll recommend that it just stays going for the typical style regarding footers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a look at the epigraph manual, but could not find code to redefine the page style. (But I am also a bit lost in all the code)

Comment: @Knallbert I have extended my answer which requires you to do some work. Please never edit the code of a package but instead make a copy and edit that.

Comment: Thank you, that is working perfectly!